# How can I calculate Residual Standard Error in R for Test Data set?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have split the Boston dataset into training and test sets as below:

```
  library(MASS)
  smp_size <- floor(.7 * nrow(Boston))
  set.seed(133)
  train_boston <- sample(seq_len(nrow(Boston)), size = smp_size)
  train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(Boston)), size = smp_size)
  train_boston <- Boston[train_ind, ]
  test_boston <- Boston[-train_ind,]
  nrow(train_boston)
  # [1] 354
  nrow(test_boston)
  # [1] 152
```

Now I get the RSE using lm function as below:

```
  train_boston.lm <- lm(lstat~medv, train_boston)
  summary(train_boston.lm)
  summary(train_boston.lm)$sigma
```

How can I calculate Residual Standard error for the test data set? I can't use lm function on the test data set. Is there any method to calculate RSE on test data set?

Answer (score 3):

Here your residual standard error is the same as

```
summary(train_boston.lm)$sigma
# [1] 4.73988

sqrt(sum((fitted(train_boston.lm)-train_boston$lstat)^2)/
    (nrow(train_boston)-2))
# [1] 4.73988
```

you loose are estimating two parameters so your degrees of freedom is `n-2`

With your test data, you're not really doing the same estimation, but if you wanted to calculate the same type of calculation substituting the predicted value from the model for your new data for the fitted values from the original model, you can do

```
sqrt(sum((predict(train_boston.lm, test_boston)-test_boston$lstat)^2)/
    (nrow(test_boston)-2))
```

Although it may make more sense just to calculate the standard deviation of the predicted residuals

```
sd(predict(train_boston.lm, test_boston)-test_boston$lstat)
```

Comment: I get the RSE in test set lower than in training set? Is this always the case?

Comment: No. The test set is completely independent. You could make a test set to get whatever RSE you want. This is because RSE doesn't mean the same thing in a test set as it does in the training set.